# Combinatoric proof $p^2$ divides combination ${2p\choose p}-2$.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Give a combinatoric proof for this problem for primary $p$:
$$
p^2 \left| \Big(\begin{array}{cc}2p\\p\end{array}\Big)-2\right. 
$$

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^p{p\choose i}^2 = {2p\choose p}\implies \sum_{i=0}^p{p\choose i}^2-2 = \sum_{i=1}^{p-1}{p\choose i}^2$. Then, use the fact that when $p$ is prime we have $p|{p\choose i}$ for all $i={1,2,...,p-1}$.

Comment: @LazyLee Thank you very much. I need a combinatoric proof. (Choosing sth of sth else...)

Comment: I'm very interested in whether there's a combinatoric proof too, that's why I didn't post as an answer :p

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193635/prove-binom2p1p-equiv2-mod-p-when-p-is-any-prime) is a combinatorial proof, but for $\binom{2p+1}{p}-2$. Adapt it to your case.

Comment: I would consider the first part of what @LazyLee wrote an argument that would appear in combinatorics setting - so, "combinatorial," and indeed even bijective if you look at the combinatorial proof underlying the equality in the first place. Plus we can prove $p\mid\binom{p}{i}$ combinatorially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{X}=\{0,1\}\times\{1,2,\cdots,p\}$ and let $\mathcal{S}$ be the collection of all $p$-subsets of $\mathcal{X}$, except for the two subsets $\{0\}\times\{1,\cdots,p\}$ and $\{1\}\times\{1,\cdots,p\}$.

Interpret the second coordinate as an integer mod $p$. Consider the functions $f_{k,l}$ defined by

$$ f_{k,l}(x,y)=\begin{cases} (x,y+k) & x=0 \\ (x,y+l) & x=1 \end{cases} $$

Given any $A\in\mathcal{S}$, we have $f_{k,l}(A)=A$ if and only if $(k,l)=(0,0)$. Therefore we partition $\mathcal{S}$ into groups of $p^2$ members, where any two $A,B\in\mathcal{S}$ are in the same group if and only if $B=f_{k,l}(A)$ for some $(k,l)$. (Exercise: why does each group have $p^2$ members?)

---

Here is the advanced view of the above argument. If $G$ acts on $X$ and $H$ acts on $Y$ then there is a canonical induced action of $G\times H$ on $X\sqcup Y$. Thus, $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$ acts on $\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{Z}_p$. If we use the choose notation $\binom{X}{k}$ to represent the collection of $k$-subsets of $X$, then

$$\mathbb{Z}_p^2 ~\textrm{ acts freely on }~ \binom{\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{Z}_p}{p}-\left\{ \begin{array}{c} \{0\}\times\mathbb{Z}_p, \\ \{1\}\times\mathbb{Z}_p \end{array} \right\}.$$

If $G$ acts freely on $X$ then $X\cong G\sqcup\cdots\sqcup G$ as $G$-sets, and in particular $|G|$ divides $|X|$.